# Find matching values of rows and extract them separately, without specifying the matching value (key)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to extract rows with matching Sample_ID in the dataframe below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1.0, 2.3,0.2,0.53], [2, 3.35, 2.0,0.2,0.65], [2,3.4, 
               2.0,0.25,0.55], [3,3.4,2.0,0.25,0.55]],
               columns=["Sample_ID", "NaX", "NaU","OC","EC"])\
               .set_index('Sample_ID')
```

In the above dataframe, df1, I would like to get only the rows with Sample_ID of "2". Is there a way to do this without specifying the matching values, the key?

The result I am looking for is:

```
       NaX NaU OC  EC
Sample_ID                  
   2   3.35    2.0 0.20    0.65 
   2   3.40    2.0 0.25    0.55
```

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: Did you try that? That raises a `KeyError` for me.

Comment: same here, key error

Comment: I just did `df1.ix[2]` and that worked for me.

Comment: @CoryMadden `ix` is deprecated, use loc/iloc or boolean indexing

Comment: Thanks, @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. That's what I've used in the past, but I was just copying gionni's method. Good to know, though.

Comment: Didn't see he set `Sample_ID` as index, also didn't test before posting, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#indexing-selection):

```
df.loc[2]
```

Output:

```
            NaX  NaU    OC    EC
Sample_ID                       
2          3.35  2.0  0.20  0.65
2          3.40  2.0  0.25  0.55
```

To answer comment question you can create a dictionary and store the groups like this:

```
list_of_df = {}
for n,g in df1.groupby(level=0):
    list_of_df[n] = g
```

Comment: instead of specifying the Sample_ID, is there a way to extract them automatically into different DataFrames as groups with matching Sample_ID? The reason I ask this is because, with a larger dataframe, I will not know the Sample_ID numbers that have matching values. Thanks.

Comment: list_of_df = {}
for n,g in df1.groupby(level=0):
    list_of_df[n] = g

Comment: This solution works for me! Is there a way to get the list_of_df values with array greater than 1 set?

Comment: [i for i in list_of_df if len(list_of_df[i]) > 1]

Comment: Thanks, I modified your code as below:                                             
  list_of_df = {} 
  for n,g in df1.groupby(level=0):
        list_of_df[n] = g
        if len(list_of_df[n])<2:
           list_of_df[n] = {}

Comment: If you only want to store those dfs that are greater that 1, you can use filter.   df1.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: x.shape[0] > 1)

Comment: This is awesome, lambda functions are just great. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Boolean Indexing will do it. `Sample_ID` is the index, so you need to use the condition on `df1.index`.

```
In [34]: df1[df1.index == 2]
Out[34]: 
            NaX  NaU    OC    EC
Sample_ID                       
2          3.35  2.0  0.20  0.65
2          3.40  2.0  0.25  0.55
```

As Scott Boston mentions, `df.loc` is another great alternative.

Comment: Thanks!  
Instead of specifying the Sample_ID, is there a way to extract them automatically into different DataFrames as groups with matching Sample_ID? The reason I ask this is because, with a larger DataFrame, I will not know the Sample_ID numbers that have matching values.

Comment: @SureshRaja You can groupby index and then extract the groups you want.

Comment: @SureshRaja `df1.groupby(level=0)`

Answer (score 3):

```
g = df1.groupby(level=0)
```

Then grab any group you'd like with `g.get_group(2)`

```
            NaX  NaU    OC    EC
Sample_ID                       
2          3.35  2.0  0.20  0.65
2          3.40  2.0  0.25  0.55
```

But this is more involved than it needs to be.  Just choose @ScottBoston's answer.

Comment: `get_group`, brilliant.

Comment: I'll accept the compliment!  But maybe a little overstated for `get_group`.